# PC freezes for a few seconds with HDD light on but no CPU activity

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

My laptop (ASUS G73jw) sometimes gets in a state where it will repeatedly (every 10 seconds or so) "freeze" - the Task Manager CPU usage goes to zero - and then recover after a few seconds. The HDD light is on during the freeze.

Having browsed for a solution, I have installed Windows Performance Analyzer, which shows clearly that during the freezes:

- the CPU is idling
- the Disk I/O stops
- the Disk usage is at max(!)

I've run chkdsk, no defrag needed, etc etc. The disk is a Seagate Momentus XP (hybrid SSD/HDD). I tried Acronis Drive Monitor but it says the drive is healthy.

What else can I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have seen this, it was my disk that was actually starting to go down the tubes.  If you are getting a lot of retries on the disk, but the data is eventually read successfully, the minimal tools might not even show you are having a problem.  This includes Windows, since it would not report anything,and thus Acronis would not report anything in this case.

Comment: Thanks - I'll see if I can get it replaced under warranty. I read that the XT has a 5 year warranty. Also need to try Seagates own diag tools.

Comment: SeaTools didn't show anything - I bought a new Momentus XT (750GB) drive, and the problem is gone. So it must have been the drive.

Comment: @Dan Yes , it was.Had a laptop which was very slow and doing the same thing, it also had S.M.A.R.T failure but didn't buy a new HDD and thinking it was a virus (noobish, but another laptop had this message and didn't have problems).Then it stopped booting and wouldn't work. Bought a new HDD and installed it , problem solved and nice fast laptop